# Javascript not rendering function as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok i have a this view

```
<input type="input" class="form-control mortgage-refinance-only" id="mortgage-cash-out-tenure" placeholder="">
      <span class=" cash-out-tenure-error hidden" style="color:red; font-size: 10px">Value can be 'NA' or greater than 1</span>
```

and i have this javascript function

```
$('#mortgage-cash-out-tenure').change(function(){
    var cashOutTenure = $('#mortgage-cash-out-tenure').val();

    if(cashOutTenure != 'NA' || cashOutTenure < 1){
        $('.cash-out-tenure-error').removeClass("hidden");
    else {
        $('.cash-out-tenure-error').addClass("hidden");
    }
  });
```

Ok basically, if the value of the input tag is not 'NA' or if it is less than 1, it should make the span visible with the error message else it shud not display the error msg.

But it doesnt seem to work properly. If it is not equal to 'NA' the error is loded correctly but if the value is numerical, it still displays the error message.

Whats wrong with the code?
Any help assistance is well appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is this really the actual code? There is a JavaScript syntax error in it. You should copy the actual code.

Comment: You miss left bracket before `else`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your code. Also, your `if` statement does not match your textual description.

Given your desired functionality, the `if` statement should be:

```
if (cashOutTenure == 'NA' || cashOutTenure >= 1) {
    $('.cash-out-tenure-error').addClass('hidden');
} else {
    $('.cash-out-tenure-error').removeClass('hidden');
}
```

When you negate clauses in an OR or an AND expression, you need to be careful about comparison operators and also about changing OR to AND (and vice versa). Repeat [DeMorgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s%20laws) to freshen up on these concepts.

Your original code: `if(cashOutTenure != 'NA' || cashOutTenure < 1)` evalates to `true` any time that the value of `cashOutTenure` is something else than `'NA'`, which includes all numeric values.

And another thing: Your error message does not match your description of the desired effect. This error message:

**Value can be 'NA' or greater than 1**

...implies that a value of `1` is not allowed. But your description says that anything **less than 1** is an error. Think about the requirements carefully before writing code *(or error messages)*...

Comment: also instead `if` OP can use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) like `$('.cash-out-tenure-error').toggleClass('hidden', cashOutTenure == 'NA' || cashOutTenure >= 1)` :-)